# insert multiple rows with specific calculated values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to insert into a table "x" number of rows based on how many "groups" and "players" a user enters into a form (that part works) but also i need to label them with specific values and cannot have player value #4.

Example:
if a user says they need 2 groups and 6 players. it means there are 2 groups of 6 players each so i will need to insert 12 records into a table and it should look something like this:

```
id     group     player     
1      1         1
2      1         2
3      1         3
4      1         5
5      1         6
6      1         7
7      2         1
8      2         2
9      2         3
10     2         5
11     2         6
12     2         7
```

here's my form..

```
<form id="setup" name="setup" method="post" action="bin/setup.php">
   <input type="text" name="groups" placeholder="# OF GROUPS" value="">
   <input type="text" name="players" placeholder="# OF PLAYERS" value="">
   <button class="btn" name="submit" type="submit">Insert</button>
</form>
```

and here's the code to insert records. Right now, it inserts 12 records but can't figure out how to do values of "groups" and "players"

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $group = ( ($_POST['groups']) * ($_POST['players']) );

        $sql = "INSERT INTO table (groups, players) 
        VALUES (:groups, :players)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':groups', $_POST['groups']);
        $stmt->bindParam(':players', $_POST['players']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < $tables; $i++) {
            $stmt->execute();
        }       

    header("Location:/"); 
    exit;

} else {
    header("Location:/?msg=error"); 
    exit();
}
```

any help would be great.
thanks.

**------- UPDATED VERSION -------**

- inserts rows with correct values (skips value # 4 from players column).

  ```
      $sql = "INSERT INTO table (groups, players) 
      VALUES (:groups, :players)";
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

      for($i=1; $i <= $_POST['groups']; $i++)
       for($j=1; $j <= $_POST['players']+1; $j++)
        {
          if($j == 4){continue;}
          $stmt->bindParam(':groups', $i);
          $stmt->bindParam(':players', $j); 
          $stmt->execute();
        }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to push your bind into a double loop:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (groups, players) VALUES (:groups, :players)";
for($i=1; $i <= $_POST['groups']; $i++)
  for($j=1; $j <= $_POST['players']; $j++)
  {
     $stmt->bindParam(':groups', $i);
     $stmt->bindParam(':players', $j); 
     $stmt->execute();
  }
```

Comment: thanks. that worked nicely. my only issue now is skipping value "4" in "players" column.